# Should runners be able to tell the difference between installed upgrades and agendas/assets?

Tags: android-netrunner

If a corporation installs an upgrade on a remote server, should the runner be able to tell it's an upgrade, and not an asset or agenda?

You can install multiple upgrades, but only one asset or agenda.  If you install an upgrade and an agenda/asset, does it matter how you place them on the table?  Should the runner be able to tell whether you have an agenda/asset and an upgrade, or two upgrades?

Answer (score 12):

From the [Netrunner FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/2013-February/Netrunner%20LCG%20FAQ%201.1.pdf):

> **Where is an upgrade installed in a remote server?**
>   An upgrade is
>   installed in a remote server in the same position  as an agenda or
>   asset. The Runner should not be able to tell  what type of card is
>   installed in a remote server by its position.  This is different than
>   installing an upgrade in a central server,  where it is always
>   installed in the root.

Comment: For this, I place all remote server cards next to each other, to let the runner know that there are N cards in the server.

Answer (score 0):

No, the runner should not be able to know what type of card is in the server, be it Agenda, Asset or Upgrade. The only place a runner should know what the card type is is in the central servers. This is intentional, to bait the runner into runs, particularly with upgrades like [Mumbad Virtual Tour](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10076) or [Prisec](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11040), letting the runner think the ice and upgrades are protecting points when it's just a heavy tax for the runner to pay getting into the server, letting you put the asset behind the ice next turn when they go broke.